# getCampaignByAccountId returns empty object in Bing ads API

Tags: php, bing-ads-api

We are using Bing Ads API for advertising our products through the campaign ads. We have 
accessing the function name getCampaign() referring bing ads document. Inside the getcampaign function calling the method soapCall, 
the code given below,

$bingAdsSoapClient  = $this->bingAPIClient->__soapCall (
    $actionGetCampaignsByAccountId, 
    array( $actionGetCampaignsByAccountId. 'Request' => $parametersForBingAdsAPIAccountId ),
    null,
    $this->bingAPIInputHeaders,
    $outputHeaders
);

When we execute the code it returns $bingAdsSoapClient value it comes empty, and we have the campaigns in our account but its displaying empty campaign values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified the correct campaign types in the request message (the same types that you see in Bing Ads web application)? There is a GetCampaignsByAccountId example [here at GitHub](https://github.com/BingAds/BingAds-PHP-SDK/blob/master/samples/V11/BudgetOpportunities.php#L67).

By the way next time please feel free to reach out via the [Bing Ads API forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=BingAds), and we are happy to assist promptly. Please provide the SOAP request + response + timestamp to expedite the investigation. TIP: The [troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/guides/handle-service-errors-exceptions#php-troubleshooting) has tips on how to capture the XML trace, as does [this example](https://github.com/BingAds/BingAds-PHP-SDK/blob/master/samples/V11/BudgetOpportunities.php#L87).

Best regards,
Eric